# Find an upper bound of the series $\sum_{m\in\mathbb N}\frac{1}{4\gamma^2(m-n)^2-1}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find an upper bound of the series
$$\sum_{m\in\mathbb N}\frac{1}{4\gamma^2(m-n)^2-1}$$
where $n\in\mathbb N$ and $\gamma\in\mathbb R, \gamma>1$. My approach:
$$\frac{1}{\gamma^2}\sum_{m\in\mathbb N}\frac{1}{4(m-n)^2-\frac{1}{\gamma^2}}=\frac{1}{\gamma^2}\sum_{m\in\mathbb N}\frac{1}{4(m-n)^2-1+1-\frac{1}{\gamma^2}}\leq \frac{1}{\gamma^2}\sum_{m\in\mathbb N}\frac{1}{4(m-n)^2-1}$$
I now think that I have to apply the telescopic series but I have problems with the shift of $-n$. Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

$$\frac{1}{4\gamma^2(m-n)^2-1}\le \frac{1}{2\gamma^2(m-n)^2}$$ for any $m\ne n.$

Answer (score 0):

Split your sum into $\sum_{ m \leq n} + \sum_{m > n}$, and in the second sum use what @mfl suggested (I don't understand why he has a factor of $2$ in the denominator instead of the original $4$), change the summation variable from $m$ to $k = m-n$, and finally use $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1 {n^2} = \frac {\pi^2} 6$.